# Solving the Knapsack Problem with a road network on QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path, network-analysis

I have a road network with weights assigned based on building density (i.e., how many buildings consider a given road segment the closest road). E.g., in the image below red indicates road segments with higher building density, white indicates less building density.

I need to select a sub-segment of roads starting from points on the road indicated in green such that the maximum building coverage is achieved within a given length constraint. In simple terms, what is the most optimal route starting from the green road to cover the highest number of buildings with 'x' length of road.

How can I do this?

[image: Knapsack Problem on a Road Network]

Comment: Are you asking about a single continuous route, or can there be multiple routes starting from the green road, as long as the sum of their length is < 'x'

Comment: @TomBrennan There can be a combination of multiple routes, as long as the sum of their length is x and covers the highest amount of buildings.

Comment: The core of this question is network analysis, so you might be better off asking this question in a math-related forum. I don't think it's a simple answer, and most of the work is likely to be in coming up with the algorithm approach.